# npm http server during development and rewrite url

Tags: npm

I am looking for a way to run a local http-server with npm during development. I have seen there is `http-server` but I have one additional requirement. I need to rewrite the url to my backend application with a proxy. It seems the standard `http-server` that can be installed with npm is not able to do this. Is there any other plug-in that can do this?

Essentially what I need to something like this:

```
# serve files in local folder, but rewrite all request
# to /api to localhost:8080/
npm run some-http-server --rewrite "/api/(.*) localhost:8080/$1" --path .
```

So when I access `localhost/index.html` is servers the local index.html file, but when I access `localhost/api/foo` it rewrites that as `localhost:8080/foo` and proxies it to my backend application running on port `8080`.

Does a solution like this already exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) npm package is exactly what I was looking for.

Install it with:

```
sudo npm install -g local-web-server
```

Theb start it with:

```
ws -p 63342 -r '/api/*->http://localhost:8080/$1' -d myapp
```